# Mass update in Laravel Eloquent or DB

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, sql-update

Is there anyone who knows how to do this without the technique of doing it in a one query string. I mean the popular ways I see on the net is by looping in data(the updates) and generating a single update statement and then fire a query. Is it possible for an Eloquent Approach or DB without looping?

Answer (score 0):

This is posible with Eloquent, it might be necessary to enable mass-assignment, but you will get an error if so.

```
$post_data = Input::all();
$model = Model::find($id);
$model ->fill($post_data);
$model ->save();
```

or

```
$post_data = Input::all();
Model::find($id)->update($post_data);
```

Comment: Yeah I knew that. But how about mass UPDATE? any clue on how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could specify your question a bit more, to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that but in that case, you have to make the array of data that is a loop is needed to store the data in the array with respective `field_name => value` of the table.

The following is the example:

```
    $Array = array(); //This is needed to hold data while looping over $YourData

    $YourData - is the array of data you want to store in the respective table.

    foreach ($YourData as $YourDatakey => $YourDatavalue ){

    $Array = [
             'table_column_name' => $YourDatavalue['value_from_array'],
             'table_column_name' => $YourDatavalue['value_from_array'],
             'table_column_name' => $YourDatavalue['value_from_array'],
             ...... and so on
             ];

    }
$InsertQuery= YourModelName::create($Array);
```

PS:

1. YourModelName model file should have the columns in  `protected
   $fillable = ['column1','column2'....];`
2. You should `use App\Models\ModelName;` at the top of the file.